# How to know file name of sockets or pipes in /proc/[pid]/fd

Tags: linux, android, proc, socket

In Android, `#ls -l 15843/fd` gives following output,

```
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 90 -> socket:[193728]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 91 -> socket:[193729]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 92 -> socket:[192748]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 93 -> socket:[193730]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 94 -> socket:[193440]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 95 -> socket:[192749]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 96 -> socket:[192750]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 97 -> socket:[192751]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 98 -> socket:[193441]
lrwx------ u0_a179  u0_a179           2015-05-28 11:58 99 -> socket:[193442]
```

Now i tried `#readlink /proc/15843/fd/99` but it prints `socket:[193442]` same again. 
 Also tried `#grep 193442 /proc/net/unix` it prints following,

 `00000000: 00000003 00000000 00000000 0001 03 193442`

Now, how to get the file name from this socket inode ?

Comment: Sockets don't necessarily have filenames. Even if so, there may be multiple filenames pointing to the same inode. While not certain, I think you'd have to scan the filesystem to find the matching inode, assuming there is one associated with it.

Consider that the program can create a socket, open it, then immediately remove the entry from the filesystem. It might do this to prevent having to cleanup in case of a crash. You'll never find that filename.

Comment: Try 'lsof -a', which will list open files.